# Fix filename and update references using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a few files that do not have meaningful filenames. I want the filenames to be changed to the value in title element without spaces in lowercase and update references too. Can anyone help please? I am new to Python and just know that Beautifulsoup can be used to parse xml files.
Sample files are shown below -

```
Content of xyz1.xml file ->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id ="id1"><title>Test1 Topic</title><conbody>
<section>

<p>Testing this topic </p>
<p><xref href="xyz2.xml"/></p>
</section>
</conbody></concept>

Content of xyz2.xml file ->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id ="id1"><title>Test2 Topic</title><conbody>
<section>

<p>Testing this topic </p>

<p><xref href="xyz1.xml"/></p>
</section>
</conbody></concept>

Expected output ->
Content of test1_topic.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id ="id1"><title>Test1 Topic</title><conbody>
<section>

<p>Testing this topic </p>
<p><xref href="test2_topic.xml"/></p>
</section>
</conbody></concept>

Content of test2_topic.xml ->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id ="id1"><title>Test2 Topic</title><conbody>
<section>

<p>Testing this topic </p>

<p><xref href="test1_topic.xml"/></p>
</section>
</conbody></concept>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will make the change the names of the files based on a given folder from the title of the XML

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

folder=#folder name
change_href = {}
for _, _, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        file_location = os.path.join(folder, file)
        print(file_location)
        with open(file_location) as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
        change_href[file] = "{}.xml".format(soup.find_all('title')[0].text.lower().replace(" ", "_"))
for _, _, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        file_location = os.path.join(folder, file)
        with open(file_location, "r+") as f:
            content = f.read()
            for k, v in change_href.items():
                content = content.replace(k, v)
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(content)
        if file_location != os.path.join(folder, change_href[file]):
            os.rename(file_location, os.path.join(folder, change_href[file]))
```

Comment: Your code changed the filename to the format I needed. I also want the file reference included within the files to be changed to the new names. Is it possible to select files with a pattern such as files starting with xyz? Can you help please?

Comment: I've edited the code to change the hrefs according to the new files names

Comment: It worked, but, have few questions - 1) Code stopped when it found a filename same as title in the xml file. 2) To avoid this, is it possible to pass a regx to match the files that start with xyz and perform the operation?

Comment: I don't understand "1) Code stopped when it found a filename same as title in the xml file." can we explain in more details?

Comment: Example, consider a file with name -> ``` file ->test1_topic.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN" "concept.dtd">
<concept id ="id1"><title>Test1 Topic</title><conbody>
<section>

<p>Testing this topic </p>
<p><xref href="xyz2.xml"/></p>
</section>
</conbody></concept>``` In this case, since the filename is same as title, the code does not proceed futher. That is why, I want to select the files with a particular pattern to parse (ex: files starting with xyz) and change only name of files which do not have meaningful names.

Comment: I tried and it worked for sample files but when I tried the code for my actual files, I got a few errors, that is because the title element has <keyword keyref="abc"/>. Is there a way for the code to ignore such content and include only the content that is in title element? ```<title>Authentication protocol <keyword keyref ="abc"/>for connections </title>``` The filename should be authentication_protocol_for_connections. Due to addition of keyword, the title element may be ended in next line and not in the same line.

Comment: One more hurdle that I faced is - once a file got renamed to say, overview.xml that was taken from title element and further again there is another file with same title element, then I get the error - WinError183 Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Comment: That it's correct you can't rename 2 files to the same name to overcome it you can create a counter that will create file1.xml and file2.xml as an example. If the code helped you to solved your question please vote up and mark the answer.

Comment: Your code definitely helped me get started. I will try to do further customizations.